Trying to load a pre-trained model directly
I am trying to instanciate a model (ResNet50) from the tensorflow model garden, and then load checkpointed weights from the github repo directly.
The load from the checkpoint doesn't work, with the following error :
AssertionError: Found 269 Python objects that were not bound to checkpointed values, likely due to changes in the Python program.

I have created the ResNet50 model from the model garden directly by creating the backbone, then the ClassificationModel containing the backbone.
resnet = tfm.vision.backbones.ResNet(50, input_specs=keras.layers.InputSpec(shape=[None, 224, 224, 3]))

model = tfm.vision.classification_model.ClassificationModel(backbone=resnet, num_classes=1000, input_specs=keras.layers.InputSpec(shape=[None, 224, 224, 3]))

optim = keras.optimizers.SGD(0.001)
loss = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
model.compile(optim, loss, metrics=[tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])

Then, I load the model checkpoint from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/MODEL_GARDEN.md, using the following :
status = model.load_weights("/home/tleberre/ssd/models/ckpt-62400")
status.assert_consumed()

This returns the error detailed above, and loads nothing into the model. It seems that the checkpoint weights and the model weights are mismatched. What did I do wrong ?

This error arises when there's a mismatch between the model architecture you created and the architecture used to generate the checkpoint weights you're trying to load. This can happen due to various reasons.Missing Layers/Variables: If you've modified the model after creation (e.g., adding/removing layers), weights won't be available for the changes.Model Garden Version Incompatibility: Checkpoints might not be compatible with different Model Garden versions.

Make sure that the ResNet50 model architecture you're using for inference is the same as the one used for training. Even small differences, such as layer naming or ordering, can cause issues with loading weights.
